# System.NullReferenceException in both cases when checking context.Request.Path

Tags: c#, .net

```
try
{
   if (context.Request.Path != null) // this will throw NullReferenceException exception.
   {
   }
}
catch (System.NullReferenceException)
{
   if (context.Request.Path == null) //System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
   {
   }
}
```

I'm trying to check the value of context.Request.Path. The issue here is that I'm having System.NullReferenceException in both cases when checking `context.Request.Path`.

context is of type `HttpContext`

Comment: *Don't* catch `NullReferenceException`. Fix it instead. This is almost always an application bug. What is the actual *full* exception message, including the stack trace? This will show you where the exception was thrown and the chain of calls that lead to it.

Comment: Catching  NullReferenceException is for the purpose of this question

Comment: Where are you calling this code? An HttpContext refers to a single request. It has no meaningful value outside that request. If you try to use its value after the request completes, you'll get errors or useless data. If you try to use it eg in a background service, you'll get errors because has probably finished by the time the background service tries to read that HttpContext

Comment: `Catching NullReferenceException is for the purpose of this question` that only helps if you post the full exception text. Otherwise it's better to let the debugger break at the point where the error is thrown. You can easily get the text with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup

Comment: does the rest of your code look like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/7hJnGK

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not that the `Path` is null. The problem is that either `context` or `context.Request` is null. You could use [null propagation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#null-conditional-operator) to check:

```
if (context?.Request?.Path != null)
{

}
```

Comment: nope, this is not the case. Both context and Requests are populated. Getting System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @user1765862 in that case that could mean that `Request` or `Path` are computed properties that throw `NullReferenceException` when accessed. Please use the debugger to see where the original exception comes from.

Comment: @user1765862, you are wrong, check again, assume nothing.

Comment: They may be populated by the time you break, but are you sure they're populated when the code is actually executed?